# Regex to extract hyperlink containing a specific word

Tags: regex

I need to extract a hyperlink, containing a specific word in the url, from a piece of text. Example;

"This is a text with a link to some page. Click this link `<a href="/server/specificword.htm>this is a link to a page</a>` to see that page. Here is a link that doesn't have the word "specificword" in it: `<a href="/server/mypage.htm>this is a link without the word "specificword" in the url</a>`"

So, I need to parse this text, check the hyperlinks to see if one of them contains the word "specificword", and then extract the entire hyperlink. I would then end up with this:

```
<a href="/server/specificword.htm>this is a link to a page</a>
```

I need the hyperlink that has specificword in the url eg. /server/specificword.htm, not in the link text

One regex I have tried, is this one: `/(<a[^>]*>.*?</a>)|specificword/`
This will match all hyperlinks in the text, or "specificword". If the text has multiple links, without the word "specificword", I will get those too.

Also, I have tried this one, but it matces nothing:

```
<a.*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\'>]*specificword[^"\'>]*)["\'][^>]*>.*?<\/a>
```

My regex skills end here, any help would be great....

Comment: Is there a quote before `>` or it is actually missing?

Comment: What's your programming language/tool/environment?

Comment: C# and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this for all the a tag:

```
/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"[^"]*SPECIFICWORD.*?<\/a>/
```

or just for the link (in the first capture group):

```
/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"([^"]*SPECIFICWORD[^"]*)/
```

If you use php, for the link:

```
preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"\K[^"]*SPECIFICWORD[^"]*/', $text, $results);
```

Comment: Thanks all of you!!! Alot of great and helpful answers. I'm going to accept this as the correct answer, since it was the first one to come in. Wish I could acceps all of your answers...

Answer (score 6):

This one should suit your needs:

```
<a href="[^"]*?specificword.*?">.*?</a>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3f223)

---

If you want to allow other attributes on your anchor tar, and be more premissive about inner spaces, you could try:

```
<a( [^>]*?)? href="[^"]*?specificword.*?"( .*?)?>.*?</a>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3f226)

---

You could also of course use non-capturing groups `(?:...)`:

```
<a(?: [^>]*?)? href="[^"]*?specificword.*?"(?: .*?)?>.*?</a>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3f229)

---

And finally, if you want to allow simple quotes for your `href` attribute:

```
<a(?: [^>]*?)? href=(["'])[^\1]*?specificword.*?\1(?: .*?)?>.*?</a>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3f22c)

---

Last but not least: if you want to capture the URL, just put parentheses around the `[^\1]*?specificword.*?` part:

```
<a(?: [^>]*?)? href=(["'])([^\1]*?specificword.*?)\1(?: .*?)?>.*?</a>
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3f22f)

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate this. I can really learn a lot from all of you!!

Answer (score 3):

The final regex you tried almost had it. Try this alteration of it:

```
<a\s.*?href=["']([^"']*?specificword[^"']*?)[^>]*>.*?<\/a>
```

The main difference is making the quantifiers "lazy".

Comment: I tried this one, and it seems to return the hyperlink with the specificword in the link text, not in the url. I need the hyperlink with the word in the url... I'm trying some things in a regular expression designer. It's very close...

Comment: This seems to match `<ahref"specificword></a>` though (see the missing space between `a` and `href`).

Comment: You're right, I used it the wrong way, sorry. However, I'm going to accept another answer, sinced it came first... Thanks!!

Comment: @sp00m Good point. I've edited the question to include a minimum of 1 space.

Answer (score 2):

try this pattern this is exact requirement you want

```
(?=.*href=\"([^\"]*specificword[^"]*)")<a [^>]+>
```

if you want only url value use Groups[1]
Like:

```
Regex.match("input string",@"(?=.*href=\"([^\"]*specificword[^"]*)")<a [^>]+>").Groups[1].value;
```